# How to add additional attributes to input field with django?

Tags: django

I need something like this:

```
<div>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="attr1" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="attr2" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="attr3" value="false">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="attr11" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="attr22" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="attr33" value="true">
</div>
```

I need to attach some extra non-standard attributes to each field. What is the best way to do this? How to realize above example? I can do this with custom template in django but it is unnecessary client-server communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any attributes you want in the form. For example you can set `rows` and `cols` attributes like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.Textarea(attrs={'my_attr': 'and_value'})
```

The rendered result is:

```
<textarea my_attr="and_value" name="description" id="id_description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Ok that. But i need to attach non standard attrs. Like myrows not rows

Comment: You can add any kind of attributes this way.